# Quicksight reports from schema based multi tenancy on postgres

Tags: amazon-quicksight

For a multi tenant SaaS product we want to be able to build canned reports for customers from a schema based tenancy model (not the row level security). Is it possible to do this on AWS Quicksight? It looks like you need to select a particular table and create analysis.

Is there anything like a report template or an api to create a report on each schema?

Comment: Hi Vishal, did you find any solution for this in quicksight?

Comment: Hi Vishal, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Nope, we didn't end up using quicksight because of this. QuickSight recently announced new APIs to programatically setup dashboards and datasets https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/evolve-your-analytics-with-amazon-quicksights-new-apis-and-theming-capabilities/  - That might be something to look at.

Comment: Not sure if I'm too late to answer but you can make use of namespaces in quicksight.